# hidden form update button where a form has 2 submit buttons?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that has 2 buttons, one for "Checkout" and the other for "Update Cart".

```
<input name="update_cart" type="submit" id="update_cart" value="Update Cart">

<input name="checkout" type="submit" id="checkout" value="Checkout" disabled onclick="return confirm_checkout();">
```

When someone updates the quantity, it calls this jQuery:

```
<script>$(function() {
$('#quantity_select').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find('#update_cart').click()
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, I'd like to hide the "Update Cart" button because it's not needed as it's already called with the jQuery whenever someone updates the quantity. How do I achieve it so that the button still works but it's not visible? Like as a hidden value maybe? But then it couldn't execute the ".click", right?

Comment: Do you want to hide it inside the `change` handler? How it becomes visible again?

Comment: Have you tried `hide()`?

Comment: You can also only use `$('#update_cart')` selector instead of doing `$(this).closest('form').find('#update_cart')` since id attributes are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just hide it with css

`display:none`

see here 
http://jsfiddle.net/qnot117n/

Comment: Doh! How did I not think of that. Thanks! :)